# How to draw a gradient line on a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, line, draw, linear-gradients

Im looking for a function to draw a gradient line. It can be accomplished by drawing a gradient rectangle 1px wide, but somehow I always get the wrong colors. I think because the positions inside the rect are relative, and I need to draw the line using absolute positions.

So can someone show a quick example function?

Comment: With a little bit of code it would be much easier to help you... [Here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-linear-gradients/) is an example.

Comment: post sample code what you are trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function, it should accomplis gradient line drawing

```
function drawgradientline(x,y,height){
     var grd = context.createLinearGradient(x, y, 1, height);

      grd.addColorStop(0, '#12a6eb');   

      grd.addColorStop(1, '#ebc711');
  context.fillStyle = grd;
  context.fill();
}
```